Is it possible to use $a^x + b^x (\bmod p)$ and $a^{x+1} + b^{x+1} (\bmod p)$ to find $a^{x*(p-1)/q} + b^{x*(p-1)/q} (\bmod p)$, q is factor of p-1?
We know:

$p$ is large prime and $p - 1$ is a smooth number
$ct1  = a^x + b^x  (\bmod p)$
$ct2 = a ^ {x+1} + b^{x+1}  (\bmod p)$
$a$ and $b$

The goal is to find $x$, so I try to implement Pohlig Hellman but it seems to be impossible
to find $a^{x(p-1)/q} + b^{x(p-1)/q}  (\bmod p)$ ($q$ is a factor of $p-1$) without know $a^x (\bmod p)$ and $b^x (\bmod p)$. Can anyone help me? I appreciate any answer.

"$p$ is large prime and a smooth number" - that is self-contradictory - a smooth number (by definition) has no large prime factors, while a large prime number has a large prime factor (itself).  Please correct your question...

thanks for your help, I edited the questions to make it clear

Are $a$ and $b$ known?

$a$ and $b$ are known, sorry for the confusion

HINT: $(a(ct1)-ct2)/(a-b)$


The goal is to find $x$

I assume you know the values of $a, b$.  If so, it sounds easy enough.
We have:
$$ct1 = u + v$$
$$ct2 = au + bv$$
(where $u = a^x$ and $v = b^x$, and the equations are $\bmod p$).
Then, simple algebra gives us $u = (ct2 - b \cdot ct1)(a - b)^{-1}$.
Once you have $u = a^x$, it is easy to recover $x$ (because, as you stated, $p-1$ is smooth, and so PH recovers it nicely).

If you don't know the values of $a, b$, then you have two equations in three unknowns: $ct1 = a^x + b^x$ and $ct2 = a^{x+1} + b^{x+1}$ have three unknowns $a, b, x$ - most likely (I haven't checked), there are a large number of solutions.
